# Show a UWP Custom control within Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, uwp, controls

How do I consume a custom UWP control within the Xamarin Forms project?

Comment: use a custom renderer

Comment: If the following is helpful please consider accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I consume a custom UWP control within the Xamarin Forms project?

For using custom uwp control within Xamarin forms, you could refer [**Implementing a View**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view) document. And this is related [code sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/CustomRenderers/View/).

> Xamarin.Forms custom user interface controls should derive from the **View** class, which is used to place layouts and controls on the screen. This article demonstrates how to create a custom renderer for a Xamarin.Forms custom control